# Ember 'belongsTo' relationship not connecting 2 application models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this working ember snip:
http://jsfiddle.net/wUC9w/

with the following 2 models:

```
App.Card = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr("string")
  description: DS.attr("string")
  template: DS.belongsTo("template", {async: true})

App.Template = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr("string")
  cards: DS.hasMany("card", {async: true})
```

However it's refusing to connect the two models in the cards view, (it doesn't get the title of the linked template). I've tried using {async: true} side-loading and preloading the related template model in the app but ember still doesn't connect the two.

I've looked all over the ember docs and asked in IRC with much help but no luck,
Any observations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: solved it!

on a belongsTo relationship the json for the fk should be name_id (so in this case template_id).

For reference:
[https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#underscored-keys-_id-and-_ids]

Comment: That's only if you're using the active model serializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks kingpin2k,

on a belongsTo relationship the json for the fk should be name_id (so in this case template_id) when using the active model serializer.

For reference:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#underscored-keys-_id-and-_ids

Comment: I don't get it. I'm having the same issue. Can you please post your code?? Thanks

Comment: Note the _id and _ids on the mockjax json for the has many and belongs to.